# UIColor clearcolor works in 3.2iOS sdk but not on 4.3 why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

my code is --

```
    [view setOpaque:NO];
    [view performSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

this same code works absolutely fine with 3.2 ios sdk [View will be transparent] but 
when i try to run it on 4.3 view which uses this code comes up with a gray background.

Comment: Did any of our answers fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just do:

```
     view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Or

```
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Try again but without the setOpaque, maybe it has diferent behaviour

Answer (score 0):

may be different default value of `view.opaque` in those versions